# Unrolling multiple arguments as keywords

Tags: clojure

I have this function which in a xml structure gives me the id of a parent node.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [clojure.data.zip.xml :as cdzx]))

(defn id-of-parent [zipper child-id node1 node2 node3 node4]
  (cdzx/xml-> zipper node1 node2 node3 node4
    (cdzx/attr= :Id child-id) zip/up zip/up (cdzx/attr :Id)))
```

It would be called like

```
(id-of-parent zipper child-id :Foos :Foo :Bars :Bar)
```

I would now like to make this function more general by replacing the four "node" with a simple "& path" so I can use any number of nodes to set a path.

```
(defn id-of-parent [zipper child-id & path]
  (cdzx/xml-> zipper ????path????
    (cdzx/attr= :Id child-id) zip/up zip/up (cdzx/attr :Id)))
```

What is the proper way of unrolling the sequence of keywords to single keywords?

Answer (score 4):

the [unquote-splicing feature of the syntax-quote](http://clojure.org/reader) function is almost always used in building function calls in macros, though it happens to be a good fit for building function calls in general.

```
(defn id-of-parent [zipper child-id & path]
        (apply cdzx/xml-> `(~zipper ~@path
          ~(cdzx/attr= :Id child-id) ~zip/up ~zip/up ~(cdzx/attr :Id))))
```

because [xml->](http://clojure.github.com/data.zip/index.html#clojure.data.zip.xml/xml-%3E) is a function and not a macro you can build calls to it using apply

Comment: This approach does not work. Eg. the call to `attr=` or `zip/up` are not evaluated. So you get a list or a symbol instead of the predicates.

Comment: forgot to the rest of them, fixed

Comment: Fixed missing zipper unquote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`.

```
(defn id-of-parent
  [zipper child-id & path]
  (->> [(cdzx/attr= :Id child-id) zip/up zip/up (cdzx/attr :Id)]
    (concat path)
    (apply cdzx/xml-> zipper)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply can be used like:

```
(defn id-of-parent
  [zipper child-id & path]
  (let [pred [path (cdzx/attr= :Id child-id) zip/up zip/up (cdzx/attr :Id)]]
    (apply cdzx/xml-> zipper (flatten pred))))
```

Comment: This gives me a ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj  clojure.core/with-meta (core.clj:211)